# Is it possible to convert synchronous function call with output of Either[Throwable, Unit] to Future[Either[Throwable, Unit]]?

Tags: scala, monads, future, scala-cats, either

I have this scala function that produces `Either[Throwable, Unit]` in which there is a **retry** call. The someClient.insertDetails function returns an entity; not a Future or anything, just an instance of a case class.

```
  def insertDetails(phone: String, id: ID): Either[Throwable, Unit] = {

    withRetry(3) {
      someClient.insertDetails(phone, id)
    }.toEither
      .flatMap(res => )
      .leftMap(t => new Throwable(t.toString))
  }
```

The **retry** implementation looks like this.

```
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  private def withRetry[T](retries: Int)(f: => T): Try[T] = {
    Try(f) match {
      case x: Success[T] => x
      case _ if retries > 1 => withRetry(retries - 1)(f)
      case f => f
    }
  }
```

Now, I am using `insertDetails` in a stream pipeline. The function in the pipeline that calls `insertDetails` looks like this.

```
  def createAccount(createAcc: CreateAcc): Future[Either[Throwable, Account]] = createAcc match {
    case CreateAcc(phone, id) => (for {
      acc <- EitherT(repo.get(id).map(_.leftMap(error => CustomError(errorMessage = Some(error.toString)))))
      something <- EitherT.fromEither[Future](someOtherClient.createSomething(acc, id)).map { something: Something =>
        val _ = client.insertDetails(phone, something.id) match {
          case Left(t) =>
            sendToNotification(t.getMessage)
          case _ =>
        }

        Account(something.Result, id)
      }
    } yield acc).leftMap(error => new Throwable(error.toString)).value
  }
```

I noticed that by having the `insertDetails` in `createAccount`, it adds "delay" to the execution of `createAccount` as it waits for `insertDetails` to finish. The thing is, I don't need to use the response from `insertDetails` and only want it to send a notification in the case of an `Exception`. So, I am thinking to make `insertDetails` to return `Future[Either[Throwable, Unit]]` instead of `Either[Throwable, Unit]` so then it would be like "fire and forget".

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why not just `Future[Unit]`? Futures natively support failure handling.

Comment: Ofcourse you could simply wrap the execution in `Future` `Future { client.insertDetails(phone, something.id) match {.....} }`

Comment: 1565986223 has the right idea, imo. Just wrap that block of code in a Future block, and the whole thing will run on another thread determined by the dispatcher of your Execution Context. Then you won't need to wait for insertDetails and sentToNotification to finish to move on to your other code.

Comment: Is that considered a good practice? Is there another way that is considered "elegant"?

Comment: @thecruisy It's hard for me to think of some particularly elegant way of doing what you're describing since sendToNotification is fundamentally side-effecty. Wrapping the code block in a Future at least solves the problem of how to use parallelism to remove a bottleneck in your code. It's simple, even if it isn't flashy like a monad transformer, whose presence in your code I would rather have avoided if I were in your situation. That's strictly my personal opinion.

Answer (score 2):

```scala
import zio._
import zio.blocking._

type ID = Int

val someClient = new {
  def insertDetails(phone: String, id: ID): Either[Throwable, Unit] =
    id match {
      case 321 => Right(())
      case _ => Left(new Exception())
    }
}

def insertDetails(phone: String, id: ID) =
  blocking(ZIO.fromEither(someClient.insertDetails(phone, id)))
    .retry(Schedule.recurs(3))

val runtime = new DefaultRuntime {}

runtime.unsafeRun(insertDetails("321098", 321))
//()
runtime.unsafeRun(insertDetails("123456", 123).either)
//res1: Either[Any,Unit] = Left(java.lang.Exception)
runtime.unsafeRun(insertDetails("123456", 123))
//Fiber failed.
//A checked error was not handled.
//java.lang.Exception
//at $line4.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anon$1.insertDetails(<console>:5)
```